# React JSX Iterate over nested array and dynamically create elements

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In my React app, I have an array defined as below;

```
gridItems = [
    {
        "fields": [{
            "fNameField-0": {
                "id": "fNameField",
                "value": "Row1 Col1"
            },
            "lNameField-0": {
                "id": "lNameField",
                "value": "Row1 Col2"
            }
        }]
    }, {
        "fields": [{
            "fNameField-1": {
                "id": "fNameField",
                "value": "Row2 Col1"
            },
            "lNameField-1": {
                "id": "lNameField",
                "value": "Row2 Col2"
            }
        }]
    }   
]
```

I want to iterate over this array and create hidden "input" elements for each nested object. So basically, I want to dynamically create the below element

```
<input type="hidden" name={fld.id} value={fld.value} />
```

and in this case, there should be 4 input elements corresponding to each of the nested object.

Comment: What is preventing you from doing so? In other words: what is the specific issue? You have an array of objects, each object has an array of fields, so a nested iteration to create the input component for each field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all the fields in a flat array, then `map` over that to create the elements.

```js
return gridItems.flatMap(o => o.fields.flatMap(Object.entries))
        .map(([k, fld]) => <input type="hidden" name={k} key={k} value={fld.value} />);
```

Comment: Looks perfect...Just one last thing though and sorry for not making it clear in the original post....But I would want to leverage fNameField-0, fNameField-1, etc as the name of the input fields  for uniqueness of the hidden fields, instead of the nested id's which are common...

Comment: @copenndthagen I've updated my answer for that.

Comment: Awesome Man !! Way too good...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple set of array map & flat operations to flatten out the tree:

```js
const gridItems = [{
  "fields": [{
    "fNameField-0": {
      "id": "fNameField",
      "value": "Row1 Col1"
    },
    "lNameField-0": {
      "id": "lNameField",
      "value": "Row1 Col2"
    }
  }]
}, {
  "fields": [{
    "fNameField-1": {
      "id": "fNameField",
      "value": "Row2 Col1"
    },
    "lNameField-1": {
      "id": "lNameField",
      "value": "Row2 Col2"
    }
  }]
}]

const flattenedObjects = gridItems
  .flatMap(item => item.fields)
  .flatMap(Object.entries)

flattenedObjects
  .forEach(([key, value]) =>
    console.log(`key: ${key}, value.id: ${value.id}, value.value: ${value.value}`)
  )
```

To render out to JSX, we can simply map the resulting values.
You can use the output in a simple map call to achieve that.

```
return (
    {flattenedObjects.map(([key, item]) => 
        <input type="hidden" key={key} name={item.id} value={item.value} />
    )}
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am looking to render hidden input elements to the JSX (or DOM output) based on the nested object

Comment: Awesome...Looks perfect...but yeah, you are right for uniqueness of the fields...I would want to leverage fNameField-0, fNameField-1, etc as the name of the input fields and can be same for the keys as well...Hope that is also possible with the structure...

Comment: Updated my answer using the flatMap idea from @Unmitigated (great idea)

Comment: Awesome to both of you...If it was possible, I would have accepted both answers !!